# Internally reversible and externally reversible processes

Tags: thermodynamics

I am now reading about how to calculate entropy changes of a system undergoing a process, and the textbook says that to be able to calculate such a change, you need to imagine that the system is undergoing an internally reversible process between the initial and final states. Does this mean that the process can be externally irreversible? And if that is true,  can you give me an example of an internally reversible but externally irreversible process?

My understanding of the situation tells me that for a process to be internally reversible, it also should be externally reversible, because if for instance we had a system exchanging heat at a finite temperature difference, then the process will not be quasi-static and therefore not internally reversible.

Comment: I think you mean to ask for an example of reversible and irreversible process in thermodynamics. Please attach the text from textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Entropy is a state function. A change in entropy does not depend on the path taken. It only depends on the difference between the final minus the initial.

The easiest path to analyze for a change between any two points is a reversible path. Hence the recommendation to use exactly such a path.

In summary, regardless of the exact path taken by the process during a change, the entropy (and the internal energy and the enthalpy and the Gibbs energy) change in the system will be easiest to determine when it is calculated using a reversible path (of any kind appropriate).

The entropy change of the environment is typically calculated by assessing the heat flow into or out of the surroundings, leading to $\Delta_{surr} S = q/T_{surr}$ (with sign conventions duly considered).